# Title Tag and Meta Description

Tags: seo, title, database

Question is, if my title tag and meta description is getting some of content or text from DB how would this effect SEO?

e.g.
Isuzu D-Max 4x2 LS MT - Specs, Specification and Price List

Where "Isuzu D-Max 4x2 LS MT" was fetch from DB, thus this still count as complete or good title?

TIA!

Comment: Sure. Why not? As long as it describes the content.

Comment: Thanks, but i mean was thus google see's the title even if the title is something like this. <title> <php echo $title["cars']; ?> - Specs, Specification and Price List</title> is it valid for SEO? thanks!

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Are you thinking that Google would see the PHP code or something?!

Comment: Not really worried about the PHP but it's more of SEO. Is it good for SEO or bad. something like that.. thanks

Comment: As long as your PHP code is rendered on the server side, and it should be, then you should be fine. If you open your page and see the title you expect, so will G. This is because the HTML returned does not have your PHP code, but the result of your PHP code. Just make sure your titles are as good as they can be. 55 characters (there about) in length and makes sense semantically. Think more toward a sentence as much as possible. Your example seems fine to me. You can tune them over time if you need to. Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry for the duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

The mere fact that your text comes from a database would not affect SEO.

Google uses bots / web spiders to crawl the internet, and they basically work like your web browser. If you see the title and description text in your browser, google does too.

If your database content changes such that page at a given fixed URL has a title or description that changes frequently, I would expect this to be bad SEO.